# make bash script wait for a signal using and empty named pipe

Tags: bash, signals

I'm trying to make a bash script wait for a signal using and empty named pipe. I like this approach most than:

```
while : ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

because it's a kind of busy-waiting

I try:

```
trap 'echo SIGNAL!' INT
while true;
do
  read
  echo 'AFTER READ'
done < /tmp/fifo
```

where /tmp/fifo is the empty named pipe

and I get:

```
bash: /tmp/fifo: Interrupted system call
SIGNAL!
```

bash script aborts. How can I make the script keep looping when receiving the signal?
Thanks

Comment: If you just want the script to pause itself, have it send itself `SIGSTOP`; later, when you are ready for it to resume, send it `SIGCONT`. This doesn't require any special handling on the part of the script itself.

Comment: Nope, since script has been stopped, it doesn't react to signals sent to him, p.e. SIGINT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8401446/1126841):

```
trap 'echo SIGNAL!; kill $(jobs -p)' INT
read < /tmp/fifo &
wait
```

Comment: ok, that works, I just didn't want to create an additional proces

Comment: This is just a single `fork`, so the overhead is fairly minimal.

Comment: +1 for not neglecting your children, which the original answer did.  Unfortunately, this litters my console with ugly "Terminated signal 15" warnings.  Perhaps `sh -c 'trap "exit 0" TERM; read < /tmp/fifo' &` ?  Or `perl -e '$SIG{TERM}=\&exit; sleep'` ?

Comment: @pilcrow I think those are produced by the shell's job control feature, which is only active in an interactive shell.

Comment: ok,.. I see now the alternatives. I think we can conclude there are ways in shell scripting, but not as straightforward as in C, with pause() (or sigwaitinfo() for that matter)